# How to transfer contacts from Yahoo to Gmail?

Tags: google-contacts, yahoo-mail, migrate-data

How do I transfer all my contact addresses from Yahoo mail to Gmail? I have checked Gmail and can't find a contact or address directory for my contacts.

Comment: Have you exported your yahoo contacts?

Answer (score 1):

Go you your [Yahoo Mail](https://mail.yahoo.com), click "Actions", and choose "Export..."

On the subsequent dialog box, choose "Yahoo CSV".

[image: export contacts]

Save the file somewhere you'll be able to find again.

Go to Gmail. Open the Gmail menu and choose "Contacts". (Alternatively, just go to [contacts.google.com](https://contacts.google.com).

[image: Gmail menu]

Open the "More" menu and choose "Import...". Select the CSV file you downloaded from Yahoo Mail and hit "Import".

[image: import contacts]

Your contacts should now be imported. To help find them easier they will also automatically be labeled with "Imported m/d/yy" where "m/d/yy" is the current date.